# Jquery variables error

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am having an issuse with my code.

I have an input box that displays a buttons value on click.
I want for when you press a button for the value currently displayed in the input box to be stored in a variable and for it to then update and store the new button variable.

```
$('.action').on('click', function(){
    var action = $(this).val();
    alert('the newAction is:  '+ action);
});
```

num1 would contain the value and the action?

Comment: really bad by taken out the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `<button class="operation">*</button>`,
you should try [**.innerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) or [**.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$('.action').on('click', function () {
    var value1 = $('#newDisplay').val();
    alert('the first value is: ' + value1);

    var operator = this.innerHTML;
    // or $(this).text();

    alert('the newAction is:  ' + operator);
});
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B3au4/1/)

Comment: I was using the wrong variable names, I presume this will still apply if i was to just edit the variables?

Comment: @user3052295, yes. I updated my answer now with new variable names. Btw, welcome to stackoverflow. In the future do keep the question's variables and include all code you have so people can help you better.